# Store User Profile Pictures Securely on AWS S3

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm developing a little multiplayer game app which requires users to have profiles and allows them to have profile pictures.

The game servers will be hosted on AWS EC2 and as database I plan to use DynamoDB with an additional Redis Cache. To store profile pictures I want to use S3.

The S3 server will be accessible directly from the app since I dont want to route all traffic over my game servers. Now I need to create a secure way to let users
up and download profile pictures. Every user is allowed to upload his profile picture but not every other user may download it.

Uploading should not be a problem since I can use my game servers to sign a link for uploading.

My concern is more about download. There is a "friend system" in the game
and only your friends may see your profile picture. Now I though of several ways to store this pictures securely to ensure the privacy of my users.

1. Do something with the url:
   So the basic idea of this is that I will us a url that is hard to guess for an attacker.
   http://s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/profilpictures/[userid+random 128bit]
   But I dont know if thats just enough. Maybe if there are more random bits?
2. Encrypt the picture:
   Just encrypt the image. I would use AES with an 128bit key which is different for each picture and geneated on the users device. The server would store the key and give it only to the right persons.
   As url I could use http://s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/profilpictures/userid what makes the url calculatable. Downside: An attacker could calculate the url and get the encrypted picture. Is that a problem?
3. Do both:
   The approach that guarantees most privacy for my users is just a combination of the both above. But is this enough? Or maybe even too much?

So what do you think about these approaches? Is there anything I didnt think of?

Answer (score 2):

Don't overcomplicate things. Just send signed URLs to those users who should see the picture.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: Wearing the Architect hat, the S3 signed URL seems a good option, but from a mobile app developer perspective it's a pain to manage caching and image rendering with signed URLs. I've encountered a lot of performance issues rendering image with signed URLs because of the encryption/decryption involved on the S3 side, although very minor, it becomes major issue for media heavy mobile apps.

Comment: @AnBisw So what would you suggest? I'm facing with the same issue right now. On the one hand I want to strict with best practices, encrypt my db, and show images to users only, so link will not be accessible through the world or at least for few seconds and no be public bucket. so I created pre signed url everytime I shoue the users list with their avatars but it seems like overkill to do that. what do you think?